# Cannot ssh into remote instances from intermediate jump boxes in GCP

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, permission-denied

**About the Question**

I want to create a hierarchy of servers : There is a **bastian host** in one VPC allowing ssh connection only from my local IP address. Then there is one more instance (Let's call it B) in another VPC and accepts connection only from bastian host . Now there are set of instances in third VPC (all of them accept ssh connections only from B.). So it is like :
local -----> bastian host -----> Instance B--------> All other instances.
In addition to this configuration I don't want to add private ssh key to any of the instance on cloud for security purpose. I only want to store the private key on my local machine that I will use to ssh into bastian host.

**Approaches tried till now**

1. Generated ssh-key pair
2. Added public key to the metadata section of the compute engine so that its available to all the instances in the project,
3. Tried to use ssh forwarding to implement this. But i am only able to reach Instance B and beyond that it is giving me *permission denied(public key)* error.

I want to know how can i implement this scenario such that I can reach instance B's terminal and then access all other instances as mentioned. Is it possible to do it only using one ssh-key pair? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably want to add the private key to an `ssh-agent` instance on your local machine, then be sure to enable agent forwarding (using `ssh -A`) at each step so that each host on the chain can ultimately refer back to the local machine for the correct private key).

Comment: @chepner Thank you for your answer. It worked perfectly. The mistake i was doing was i was not including -A flag at each step. I was only doing it in the start (my mistake, i didn't knew what goes behind the scene in ssh-forwarding. Thanks to your last line, i now undestand it completely. ) . Also i want to ask is this method completely secure. Or any other approach i can read about to implement this. Thanks for your response .

Comment: Nothing is *completely* secure :) But there are concerns about `ssh-agent`; I am not well-versed in the details, but Wikipedia gives [an overview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent#Security_issues). I think the general idea is that you can trust it to the extent you trust the machines that will use the socket to communicate back to the local host.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help @chepner